# 09 Honda Odyssey No Start

Tags: honda, starting, odyssey

This one was a good one... or at least a little amusing... lack of pictures on this one it was cold and not fun being outside. 09 Honda Odyssey 3.5l comes in and doesn't start. Engine cranks over, nothing happens. Sounds like it has good (enough) compression. Checked for codes...

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Nice... I think 32 is the most I've seen yet. And no engine codes...

Easiest thing to check first would be to remove the engine cover and backprobe one of the coils and check for power, ground and a trigger. It all checks out, so on to fuel. Pull the fuel pump fuse and put a loop in so I could look at fuel pump current. And... nothing. OK so it's a place to start.

On to the fuel pump relay. Pulled the relay (4 pin) and checked the terminals in the Multiplex Unit. All readings taken Key On Engine Off or Cranking.

1. 12v KOEO/ground KOEC
2. 12v
3. 12v
4. 9.7v

9.7v? That's not right. Pin 4 would be the path to the fuel pump. So what's going on? Is this a short to power? Why would there be 9.7v on this wire with the relay pulled? Does the number of body codes have something to do with this? What are my next steps?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the MICU was, is? MIA.

My next three tests:

1. Scan check to verify all modules present and accounted for.
2. If all present erase all codes; any that return get investigated.
3. Install the relay with test connectors installed and take 
   the pin voltage readings with power on and while cranking.

Answer (score 0):

After wasting time gaining access to the fuel pump (removing the third row seats and pulling the carpet up)

[image]

I discovered that the fuel pump power wire was OK. The ground wire on the other hand, had the mystery 9.7v. OK, so time to take another look at the wiring diagram.

[image]

... and a ground distribution diagram.

[image]

Time to take the trim apart... and find out that the driver sliding door doesn't open. Seems like the latch is jammed. Whatever, I can work around it.

Lo and behold...

[image]

OK... Tighten that down, drive a Tek screw into the bracket, recheck the fuel pump connector for power and ground and... It starts!

So, it seems someone had removed the trim prior, trying to get the sliding  door to open. As I was removing trim I noticed a bunch of missing clips and they managed to crack the trim around the spare tire holder. As well as around the B pillar.

So the lesson is, double check your work when trying to fix something (even if what your trying to fix hasn't actually been fixed)?